# imwrite not saving frames

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save frames and their path into the Database and file storage, but somehow frames are not getting saved in the path I have provided, printing path seems to be fine , but I am only getting the directory which I am creating not the pictures inside of it  , need help in this , thanks in advance

```
 def get_frames(cap=0):
    frames = cv2.VideoCapture(cap)
    now_utc = dt.now(timezone('UTC'))
    now_local = now_utc.astimezone(get_localzone())
    
    data = {}
        

    success,image = frames.read()
    scaling_factor = 0.5
    count = 0
    while True:
    
        if not success:
            break
                # save frame as JPEG file      
        success,image = frames.read()
        image = cv2.flip(image,1)
        #adding guassian blur
        image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=scaling_factor, fy=scaling_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        
        # lower = [18, 50, 50]
        # upper = [35, 255, 255]
        # lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
        # upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")

        # mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    
        # output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, hsv, mask=mask)
        
        # no_red = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
        # if int(no_red) > 15000:
        #     Fire_Reported = Fire_Reported + 1
        count += 1
        
        cv2.imshow("frame", image)

        

        ret,buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpeg',image)
        
       

        dtString =  dt.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
        path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,f'camera_frames_{dtString}') 

        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
      
        imgName = os.path.join(path ,dt.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S')+'.jpeg')

        saved_frame = cv2.imwrite(imgName, image) 

        if count <= 20:
            camera_ins = get_or_create(db.session,Cameras,alias_name='test_cam',camera_no=1)
            frame_ins = CameraFrames(date_time=now_local.strftime(format),camera_image=imgName)
            camera_ins.frames.append(frame_ins)
            db.session.add(camera_ins)
            db.session.add(frame_ins)
            db.session.commit()

        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        


        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        

        if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
            break
```

Comment: Can you print imgName and check whether it is a legal filename (allowed characters and path) and whether the folder already exists? Can you try to change the name/path to something else that definitely works? Make sure your application has writing permissions to that folder.

Comment: According to google hit: "On Windows systems, files and directory names cannot be created with a colon (:)"

Comment: there are some white spaces involved `C:\Users\atifs\Documents\video_detect\camera_frames_17-10-2021\10/17/2021 03:43:21.jpeg` paths are like this @Micka

Comment: the strftime() call also contains **forward slashes**, which will be interpreted to separate additional **directories**. you simply didn't think about what a legal path is, or file name.

Comment: I guess the colon might be the problem. Can you try .strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I_%M_%S')+'.jpeg') and also try .jpg instead of .jpeg

Answer (score 1):

as @Micka pointed out initially I was using wrong naming conventions in frames, which was failing `imwrite` and errors where falling silent, characters like `:` are not allowed , I simply removed those